# Can SPARQL describe one which doesn't have a certain relationship?

Tags: relationship, sparql, rdf, jena, owl

[image]

the picture above is the one I get from your website.

the SPARQL above means to Find the name of any people that Alice knows

My question is :
if my owl model is like this:
[image]

and I want to Find the one who have a foaf:mbox relationship with  , but doesn't have the relation 'foaf:knows'
can the SPARQL support the feature of describe something that don‘t have a certain relationship ?

Answer (score 6):

That is handled by FILTER NOT EXISTS, i.e.:

```
SELECT ?x
WHERE {
   ?s foaf:mbox ?mbox .
   FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?s foaf:knows ?x
   }
```

}